# GWTQuery live blur not working

Tags: java, jquery, gwt, gwtquery

The following code attaches a new element with every subsequent click on the 2nd `div`. With each adding, the focus is set to the added element, so that it is ready for `blur` methods (I am setting the `tabIndex` attribute just for this purpose).

However, on clicking outside the new element, nothing happens, even though there should be a pop-up. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        VerticalPanel vert = new VerticalPanel(); 
        String foo = "<div id ='foo'>Foo</div>";
        $("#bodywrapper").append(foo);
        $("#bodywrapper").append("<div id ='boo'>Boo</div>");
        $("#boo").click(new Function() {
            public boolean f(Event e) {
//              Window.alert("foo");
                $("<div id ='goo' tabIndex = '1'>Boo</div>").appendTo("#bodywrapper").focus();
                return true;
            }
        });
        $("#goo").live("blur", new Function() {
            public boolean f(Event e) {
                Window.alert("Foo");
                return true;
            }
        });
        RootPanel.get().add(vert);

      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blur and focus events don't work with event delegation (live or delegate methods) because they're not bubbling events. JQuery introduce the special events focusout and focusin for this purpose. But GwtQuery doesn't support them yet. Please open an issue [there](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/issues/list) and they will be implemented

Comment: Oh my God. Then how do I do it? Is there no work-around? I need it badly!

Comment: add your event handler just after you add the element in the dom

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Please do it, I must implement it!

Comment: I will explain my actual code (this one here is just a dummy). I am detecting a click on an element, then sliding down another element, after which I am setting focus to it (through using `tabIndex` attribute and `focus()` method). I need to attach the `blur` handler to the slid down element...

Comment: what julien dramaix meant is that you have to call the bind method after calling the appendTo one: $("<div id ='goo' tabIndex = '1'>Boo</div>").appendTo("#bodywrapper").bind("blur", new Function()....).focus()